# Simple Twilio example of a call betwen two persons

Tags: java, twilio

Starting with this simple piece of code, that do the following:

1. Calls the CLIENT_PHONE_NUMBER.
2. When the human being at CLIENT_PHONE_NUMBER picks up the call an automatic message is played (because I am in trial account), and he is asked to press a key.
3. After he presses a key the Twiml code gets executed. In this case he heards the message "This is said by a robotic woman".
4. Then the call finishes, without "nobody" given the opportunity to talk with the client.

I want to ask you if it is possible that between steps 3 and 4, an human being, acting as telemarketer (with headphones connected to its PC), and in some way "using" the Twilio Buy Phone (=ASSIGNED_PHONE_NUMBER) could talk with the client person.
Without the need to use
`<Dial><Number>...some phone number...</Number></Dial>` in the Twiml.

```
import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Call;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.CallCreator;
import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber;
import com.twilio.type.Twiml;

public class SimpleCallWithRecording1 {

    private static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    private static final String AUTH_TOKEN  = "***********************";

    private static final String ASSIGNED_PHONE_NUMBER = "+1599999999999";   
    private static final String CLIENT_PHONE_NUMBER   = "+3499999999999"; //verified number

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   
        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

        PhoneNumber to = new PhoneNumber(CLIENT_PHONE_NUMBER);
            //In trial account this must be 'verified number'

        PhoneNumber from = new PhoneNumber(ASSIGNED_PHONE_NUMBER);

        Twiml twiml = new Twiml(
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>                    " +  
            "<Response>                                                    " +
            "   <Say voice=\"woman\">This is said by a robotic woman</Say> " +
            "</Response>                                                   " );

        CallCreator callCreator = Call.creator(to, from, twiml);
            callCreator.setRecord(true);

        Call call = callCreator.create();
        System.out.println(call);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/tutorials/overview), which is Twilio's product to make/take calls on the browser (also mobile).

With Twilio client you could implement a call center website, which seems to be what you need. The telemarketer would be waiting on that website, registered in twilio client with a certain id, let's say it is "TM001".

You could update the twiml to be:

```
<Response>                                                    
    <Say voice=\"woman\">This is said by a robotic woman</Say>
    <Dial>
         <Client>TM001</Client>
    </Dial>  
</Response>
```

In the website, your Twilio's client library will raise an event notifying about the incoming call, the telemarketer can hit up a button which you can wire to pick up the call.

The whole thing is a bit more complex than that. There are several things to consider, for example, what happens if the telemarketer is busy or there is not logged into the site waiting for call? You could set up a queue (which Twilio [also supports](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/queue-calls)), or you could play another audio maybe saying that all the reps are busy to call back later.

Twilio provides everything you need to build a web based call center with the needs that you described, I would encourage you to look at Twilio Client and all the programmable voice docs.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am going to analize Twilio Client as you suggest.

Comment: (... in my case, is the telemarketer who starts the call to the client phone)